# Cygwin show Windows drive name mappings to POSIX device files /dev/disk/sd*

Tags: filesystems, partition, posix, cygwin, block-device

In Linux I can use `df` to show me which Windows drives (like `/cygdrive/c`) correspond to the virtual files `/dev/disk/sdd1`.

```
/dev/sdf1         932G  932G     0 100% /media/sarnobat/c
/dev/sde1         299G  260G   40G  87% /media/sarnobat/d
/dev/sdd1         299G  166G  133G  56% /media/sarnobat/e
```

But Cygwin's `df` output doesn't show this:

```
C:                             312568640 210201636 102367004  68% /cygdrive/c
D:                             244187968 229638796  14549172  95% /cygdrive/d
E:                             312568640 281085516  31483124  90% /cygdrive/e
```

Is there a way to get it? I tried looking in `/proc/*` but I just can't find it anywhere. I was thinking maybe this device addressing scheme simply isn't applicable in Windows but if I look in the `/dev/` folder there is a list:

```
$ ls -l /dev/ | grep sd 
brw-rw-rw-  1 admin   None   8,   0 Jul 17  2017 sda
brw-rw-rw-  1 admin   None   8,   1 Jul 17  2017 sda1
brw-rw-rw-  1 admin   None   8,  16 Jul 17  2017 sdb
brw-rw-rw-  1 admin   None   8,  17 Jul 17  2017 sdb1
brw-rw-rw-  1 admin   None   8,  32 Jul 17  2017 sdc
brw-rw-rw-  1 admin   None   8,  33 Jul 17  2017 sdc1
brw-rw-rw-  1 admin   None   8,  48 Jul 17  2017 sdd
brw-rw-rw-  1 admin   None   8,  49 Jul 17  2017 sdd1
```

**Why I'm asking**

I want to make use of the excellent `dd` tool to make backups of my disks that are physically connected to my windows machine.

**Workaround**

I don't like this solution :(

```
for F in /dev/s* ; do echo "$F    $(cygpath -w $F)" ; done
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42618609/714112

Comment: In 2010 there didn't seem to be a better solution: http://cygwin.1069669.n5.nabble.com/associating-device-names-with-cygdrive-directories-td32395.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use /proc/partitions

```
$ cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name   win-mounts

    8     0 175825944 sda
    8     1 175824896 sda1   C:\
    8    16 1953514582 sdb
    8    17 1953512448 sdb1   E:\
```

This feature was added on 
https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ov-new.html#ov-new1.7.33

Comment: Mine doewsn't show the win-mounts column. My Cygwin version is 2014. Do you think that the version might be the issue? `CYGWIN_NT-5.1 mymachinename 1.7.27(0.271/5/3) 2013-12-09 11:57 i686 Cygwin`

Comment: Mine does. A few months late, but try updating it and seeing whether that makes a difference.

Comment: I upgraded to a 2018 build and indeed it works.

Comment: Hmmmm, I just tried this again and it doesn't show the win-mounts column. Maybe it doesn't work on XP, but does on newer versions of Windows.

Comment: You can try with `cygpath -w /dev/sdaX` for X=1.2.. and same for sdb, sdc...

Comment: @SridharSarnobat Completely independently also come back to this, and lo and behold, it no longer shows anything in the `win-mounts` columns for me either. I'm using Windows 7, so I'm guessing the Cygwin developers broke something in an update.